# Custom Transition Animations in AdapterViewFlipper

Tags: android, xml, objectanimator

I am using an AdaptorViewFlipper.

Its methods `setInAnimation()` and `setOutAnimation()` expect the resource ID of a XML with an `ObjectAnimator`.

I want the animation to scale & fade the view simultaneously.

I define this `scale_in_animator.xml` (for the sake of example I only post the **In** animation, the **Out** one is just the inverse)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="transitionScaleIn"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

And the view returned by the `AdaptorViewFlipper`'s adapter includes this function:

```
public void setTransitionScaleIn(float value) {
    setScaleX(2-value);
    setScaleY(2-value);
    setAlpha(value);
}
```

However, nothing happens. `setTransitionScaleIn` is not ever called.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `AdapterViewFlipper`'s source code:

```
  .
  .
  // We wrap the new view in a FrameLayout so as to respect the contract
  // with the adapter, that is, that we don't modify this view directly
  FrameLayout fl = getFrameForChild();
  .
  .
```

So `AdapterViewFlipper` wraps each children view inside a `FrameLayout`, so I just had to extend AdapterViewFlipper and override this function:

```
FrameLayout getFrameForChild() {
    return new FrameLayoutAnimable(getContext());
}
```

and of course create the class `FrameLayoutAnimable` extending `FrameLayout` with all the setXXXXX methods.

NOTE-> `getFrameForChild` is a package method, so your extended `AdapterViewFlipper` has to be in `android.widget` package.